# Component stops querying data from firestore when routed

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular5, angularfire2

I am experimenting with angular 5 and firestore. I created two components using material table and routed it through the root component. I linked the components to buttons to enable me switch components. The current issue with it is when I click on a button and the component switches the data is lost from the table. This is how I queried the data from firestore

```html
export class SalesServicesService {
    SalesData : AngularFirestoreCollection<Sales>;
    Sales: Observable<Sales[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.Sales = this.afs.collection('Sales').valueChanges();
   }

   addSalesData(SalesData) {
    this.afs.collection('Sales').add(SalesData);
  }

   getSales(){
     return this.Sales;
   }

}
```

This is the code I used for routing

```js
const myroute: Routes =  [
  //{ path: "", component: AppComponent},
  { path: "sales", component: SalesInventoryComponent},
  { path: "prod" , component: ProductsinventoryComponent}
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(myroute),
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyrouterModule { }
```

and this is how I did my routing in the root component html

```html
<body class ="navcol">

<button mat-raised-button color ="warn" routerLink ="/sales" >Sales Component</button>
<button mat-raised-button color ="warn" routerLink ="/prod" >Products Component</button>
<span class ="highttest"></span>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

the full project is on this link [Stackblitz-Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-firstore-table-xccgk8)

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the example code you've posted in your question but in your StackBlitz the trouble was your unnecessary subscribe in `ngViewAfterInit`, here is a fixed StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-firstore-table-dxk78e

I haven't dug in but my suspicion is that it keeping the subscription hot. Thus when you navigated back the table view, it resubscribed to a hot observable, and wasn't picking up any "new" data.